# Питон возвращает true вместо значения переменной

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, json

Добрый день,

Помогите разобраться с питоном, долгое время мучаюсь и не могу понять в чем осечка. 
Вызываю скрипт через `JS`, посылая ему переменные при помощи `JSON'а`, однако при возврате `success: function(response)` выдает значение true, хотя перед отправкой значение типа `string` и содержит нужную информацию.

`Javascript`:

```
$('.gamebuttons').on("click", function(){
    var thisButton = this.id
    var pcimages = document.querySelectorAll('.pcpics');
    test = [];
    test[0] = pcimages[0].id;
    test[1] = pcimages[1].id;
    test[2] = pcimages[2].id;
    var TestString = JSON.stringify(test);
    var thisButton1 = JSON.stringify(thisButton);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "..../pcmove1.py",
        data: {
            test:TestString,
            button:thisButton1
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            if (response = 'pcimg1' && thisButton == "rock") {
                RockRock();
            }
            else if (response == "pcimg1" && thisButton == "paper") {
                PaperRock();
            }
            .....
            else {
                alert("test");
            }
        }
    })
});
```

`Python`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ast
import json
import cgi
import random

page = cgi.FieldStorage()
listed = page.getvalue('test')
data = json.dumps(listed)
data1 = json.loads(data)
data2 = ast.literal_eval(data1)
data3 = random.choice(data2)
data4 = json.dumps(data3)

print 'Content-type: text/html\n'
print data4,
```

Странный момент, что при приеме `listed` его надо енкодить в `json` и только потом в `python`, без этого не принимает. На сервере `python 2.7`

В чем может быть проблема, голову сломал, заранее спасибо

Comment: На основе того что я вижу, рекомендую выбросить весь питон-код. Начать с *минимального* рабочего примера по обмену json-текстом с JavaScript. Если не можете минимальный пример найти, спрашивайте. Затем освоить пару методов по отладке: найти как в посмотреть точный запрос, который уходит из браузера и что браузер получает на уровне http, выучить как http запрос/ответ должны выглядеть. В качестве клиента, можно httpie/http-prompt использовать. Сделайте запросы к Python напрямую без JavaScript и посмотрите что возвращается. Это должно позволить тестировать JavaScript и Python отдельно.

Comment: @jfs спасибо за ответ. Неужели все так плохо, что только перепесывать? Возникает ли проблема из-за неправильности использования cgi  в данном случае? Можно ли в таком случае ссылку на хороший пример? Спасибо

Comment: ситуация несколько хуже чем полное отсутствие понимания что происходит. Вам необходимо освоить методы отладки (самые простые (в дополнение к выше сказанному), к примеру, откройте ptpython, руками маленький словарик задайте, сконвертируйте его в json текст, посмотрите как это выглядит, сохраните в файл json, посмотрите на файл, загрузите назад; закодируйте дважды, чтобы знать как это выглядит и не делать так никогда). Начните с [простейшего cgi-скрипта](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30516779/4279), научитесь делать к нему запросы. Отдельно, [научитесь JS запросы делать](https://goo.gl/XDZbhd)

Comment: вот полный пример как javascript и питон могут обмениваться данными в json формате: [flask-приложение, которое умеет возвращать статические html странички, js файлы, искать в sqlite базе данных, принимать параметры из javascript, отправлять результаты как json](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11749466/4279)